# how to use flashbug

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

How to use flashbug? Comparing the printscreens from addon page:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/flashbug/

with printscreen that I made:
http://img42.imageshack.us/img42/7686/flbug.jpg
http://img840.imageshack.us/img840/1255/flbug2.jpg

On my printscreens flashbug looks empty. Additionally, I made a statement trace("aaa"); and nothing appears in tab "Trace". So obviously I must be doing something wrong.

Or maybe there is a different/easier way to debug flash from a browser.

Answer (score 2):

You need to run a swf file build in debug mode.

You will not see any traces if you:

1. Use Publish Release build in Flash Builder.
2. Use next attribute while compiling with mxmlc

   *-omit-trace-statements=false*
3. Use Flah, and in the Publish Settings have "Omit trace Action" checked

If you want to test if it's problem in your swf or flash bug, Just try to serf the web with firebig opened and look at Flash Console, you will see some traces there from the sites with a swf's.

Answer (score 1):

i'm always using firebug to print debug messages from flash. there is a ExternalInterface class in actionscript3, which can be used make to calls to the firebug console, like this:

```
ExternalInterface.call('console.log', 'hello');
```

you can even pass whole objects from actionscript, ie:

```
var object = {message:'hello'}
ExternalInterface.call('console.log', object);
```

see the [docs on ExternalInterface](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0_de/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.htmlf) for further explanations.

Comment: I do this also, however this is not firebug showing the debug messages, but the browsers console log. ExternalInterface is used to perform javascript function calls in the browser - in this case it is calling `console.log` and passing in the `object` as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are using the debug version of Flash Player? To figure it out, just right click on an swf in firefox, you should see:

[image: Flash player debug]

Comment: It looks like i am not using debugger version. Although I downloaded and installed a file called: Download the Windows Flash Player 10.2 Plugin content debugger (for Netscape-compatible browsers) (EXE, 2.95MB) from page http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html. And in Settings of swf it says: You have version 10,2,153,1 installed - but there is no "Debugger" option on right click menu as you posted.. I don't know how to make this debug version to replace normal version?

Comment: Well I think you downloaded the good version (since you use FF or Chrome). You only have to run the exe to have your flash plugin replaced, perhaps restart your browser. I can't see what you could have done wrong.